# Google apps: tricky incoming emails forwarding rules

Tags: email, gmail, google-workspace

I need your help with the following question. Our company needs to have some email (let's call it mail@site.com) which will forward all incoming emails to all company users except sender and mail@site.com.

It is possible with Google Apps's Mail service?

Answer (score 1):

I would use Google Groups for this - a group email will not send back to the original sender of the message, and will (obviously) not send the message to itself. In google apps when you create a group you can select 'add all domain users' to include all users in the group (this will also automatically add new users as they are created)